# Match word but ignore end-of-sentence word

Tags: python, regex

My regex search is matching a word that is at the end of the sentence.

```
>>> needle = 'miss'
>>> needle_regex = r"\b" + needle + r"\b"
>>> haystack = 'Cleveland, Miss. - This is the article'
>>> re.search(needle_regex, haystack, re.IGNORECASE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(10, 14), match='Miss'>
```

In this case, "Miss." is actually short for Mississippi and it's not a match.  How do I ignore end-of-sentence words but also ensure that

```
>>> haystack = "Website Miss.com some more text here"
```

would still be a match.

Comment: To get a valid answer, you need to define *end of sentence*. Regex is not human language grammar/syntax-aware.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, language is fuzzy and regex is not a natural language processing tool. A feasible solution could be to exclude matches that have a punctuation mark using the regex [\p{P} Unicode category](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) followed by a space, e.g.

```
(?!\bmiss\p{P}\s)\bmiss\b
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pnOdiH/1)
<sub>*PCRE</sub>

However, to take advantage of Unicode codepoint properties with the \p{} syntax we have to use the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module (an alternative to the standard re module) that support that feature.

Code Sample:

```
import regex as re

regex = r"(?!\bmiss\p{P}\s)\bmiss\b"
test_str = ("Cleveland, Miss. - This is the article\n"
    "Website Miss.com")
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE)
for match in matches:    
    print ("Match at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```